# How can I update the quantity property of a cart item object in this Angular 13 e-commerce app?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular13

I am working on an e-commerce app who's front-end is made in Angular 13.

The below code is intended to sum the prices of the items in the cart:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '.app-top-cart',
  templateUrl: './top-cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./top-cart.component.css']
})
export class TopCartComponent implements OnInit {
  cartItems: any = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "iPhone 9",
      description: "An apple mobile which is nothing like apple",
      price: 549,
      discountPercentage: 12.96,
      rating: 4.69,
      stock: 94,
      brand: "Apple",
      category: "smartphones",
      thumbnail: "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/1/thumbnail.jpg",
      images: [
        "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/1/1.jpg",
        "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/1/2.jpg",
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "iPhone X",
      description: "SIM-Free, Model A19211 6.5-inch Super Retina HD display with OLED technology A12 Bionic chip with ...",
      price: 899,
      discountPercentage: 17.94,
      rating: 4.44,
      stock: 34,
      brand: "Apple",
      category: "smartphones",
      thumbnail: "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/2/thumbnail.jpg",
      images: [
        "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/2/1.jpg",
        "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/2/2.jpg",
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "Samsung Universe 9",
      description: "Samsung's new variant which goes beyond Galaxy to the Universe",
      price: 1248,
      discountPercentage: 15.46,
      rating: 4.09,
      stock: 36,
      brand: "Samsung",
      category: "smartphones",
      thumbnail: "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/3/thumbnail.jpg",
      images: [
        "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/3/1.jpg"
      ]
    },
  ];

  constructor() { }

  totalPrice: number = 0;

  doTotalPrice(){
    let total = 0;
    this.cartItems.forEach((item: { price: number, quantity: number }) => {
      item.quantity = 1;
      total += item.price * item.quantity
    });
    this.totalPrice = total;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.doTotalPrice();
  }

}
```

#### The goal

Whenever a new item is added to the `cartItems` array, if the item *already exists* in the array, I don't want duplicate items, I want a quantity update.

#### Stackblitz

You can see the full code **[HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r1yymn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Ftop-cart%2Ftop-cart.component.ts)**.

#### The problem

I have not been able to find a way to update `item.quantity` whenever one more piece of a product is added to the cart.

##### How can I update the quantity count?

Comment: Where will quantity come from? Is it going to be a key on each item in cartItems or via duplicated items in this array? Recommend typing cartItems

Answer (score 1):

you could create a `Map` called "basket", the key is the item ID.

when you add an item to the basket you can check if the item doesn't exist in the map, if so, add the item to the map and set quantity to 1.
Otherwise you don't need to add it to the map but increase the quantity.

another solution would be the use of an array and just push the items in the array. In the end you can count the occurences in the array.

Comment: I already have the array. It populates the cart template. I don't want duplicate items, I want a quantity update.

Comment: ok i see, it'a a bad example because you don't have multiple items.
So do you want to calculate the totalPrice or do you want to update the quantity?

Where is the function to add an item to a basket?

Answer (score 1):

Take another approach, where you create an array of available items, and an array of cart items. This should be way clearer to you.

```js
allItems = [{
  id: 1,
  title: 'iPhone 9',
  // ...
}];

cartItems = [];

// ...

addItemToCart(item) {
  this.cartItems.push(item);
}

// ...

get totalPrice() {
  return this.cartItems.reduce((p, { price }) => p + price, 0);
}
```

Comment: Since `item.quantity` is part of the `doTotalPrice` method, maybe its update should happend there, regardless of whether or not there is an `addItemToCart` method.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir this solution does not include the item quantity. The array is the reference : if you order 2 iphone 9, then you have 2 items in your array.